# How to make a simple slideshow using the jquery-ui tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow

I've been trying to learn how to make a simple slideshow using the jquery-ui tab. So far, my Google searching skills have failed me and I'm still very new at JavaScript. I already know how to make a jquery-ui tab using examples tutorials. I just want to learn how to make a simple slideshow out of it. If anyone here can help make one for me, please help.

I want the slideshow to automatically play when the page load and stop whenever the mouse is hovering over it. Also, if a sliding effect can be added, please add one also. Thank you very much.

Here's some code already set up in JSfiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/TcNJ2/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#tab" ).tabs();
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="tab">

<ul id="btn">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
</ul>

<br class="clear">

<div id="slides">
    <div id="1">Slide 1</div>
    <div id="2">Slide 2</div>
    <div id="3">Slide 3</div>
    <div id="4">Slide 4</div>
    <div id="5">Slide 5</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

The CSS is in the jsfiddle link

Comment: check this plugin.. `http://www.jqwidgets.com/Support/jqxTabs/slideshow/slideshow.htm`

Comment: great plugin, but the slide doesn't stop when you mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Carousel.

[This page](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137729/Carousel) contains several jQuery based carousel projects, in particular [this](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) may fit your need.

Explorer with the other projects too!!!